# List of items shuffles when updating an item in Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

My list of items is getting shuffled for a fraction of a second when updating a value in Firebase.

Here's my service(todos.service):

```js
...
export class TodosService {
  todos$: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>

  constructor(
     private db: AngularFireDatabase
  ) {
    this.todos$ = db.list('/todos/') as FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  }

   getToDos(filter){
    if (filter == undefined) {
      return this.todos$
    } 
    return this.todos$.map(_todo => _todo.filter(todo => todo.done == filter ));
   }

   addTodo(todo){
      todo.date = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
      this.todos$.push(todo);
      console.log('addTodo');
   }

   updateTodo(key, todo){
     this.todos$.update(key, todo);
   }

   deleteTodo(todo){
     this.todos$.remove(todo);
   }

}
```

Here's how i get the list (todos.component):

```js
....
constructor (
    private todosService: TodosService
  ){}

  getItems(){
    this.todosService.getToDos(this.filter)
                  .map(todos => todos.reverse())
                  .subscribe(todos => {
                    this.todos = todos;
                  })
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getItems();
  }
```

and how i update it (new-todo.component):

```js
...
addTodo(){
    let todo = {
      title: this.title,
      done: false
    }
    this.todoService.addTodo(todo);
    this.title = '';
  }
...
```

Here's what happens:
[image]
A point into the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: if you take the reverse() off does it still flip during the update?

Comment: It's not flipping without reverse(). I don't understand why it flips with reverse(). I'm sure i'm missing something from observables.  Also, where would it be best to sort my data?